# iTunes app name taken

Tags: app-store-connect

The name of my iOS app is already taken for `English US`.

I've noticed that I *am* able to use the name that I would like to if I make the default language `English UK` or `English CA` instead of `English US`.

Will setting the default language to `English UK` or `English CA`, and not having an `English US` langauge not allow the app to be visible in the US? Are there any other workarounds that I could use to make it so I could use the app name that I would like to for the US app store?

Comment: Wow, all this time I didn't know names were enforced unique.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, and that's why I put this as a comment instead of response, in case you only selected the same name as the other app, but for English UK, that wouldn't make your app disappear. What must be unique is the itunesconnect app name.

Answer (score 6):

As an option, you can use some long app name as iTunesConnect name e.g. ("Documents 5 - Fast PDF reader, media player and download manager", "Lifesum - Join the health movement").

This name is used on the app store page and defined on iTunesConnect when you upload the app.

The name of your binary is in your Project Setting (Bundle display name) and there you can use shorter name of your app (refering to previous example will be: "Documents" and "Lifesum").

Answer (score 3):

If you could use ***English*** ***UK*** or ***CA*** instead of ***US*** in order to achieve desired name of your **App** then go for it. Your app will not be ***invisible*** from ***US App Store***. Until and unless you ***restrict*** your app visibility from some countries which obviously you shouldn't do when ***configuring*** your App for submission.

For submission details see below links:

- [Publishing to the App Store](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution_overview/publishing_to_the_app_store/)
- [Build and Publish Your iOS App to the App Store](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/publishing-your-app/distribute-production/publish-ios)
- [How To Submit an iOS App to the App Store](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-submit-an-ios-app-to-the-app-store--mobile-16812)

Comment: So it **is** possible for one to search something on the app store and there to be several apps with the same name?

Comment: It is possible because certain apps are not available for some particular countries or region. See this: http://www.bresink.com/osx/masfaq.html

Comment: Does this language changes affect any other things?